# If Elif Traceback NameError Grade Letter Program

Tags: python

I am currently trying to code a letter grade program based off of the 0-100 Grade Scale. I am new to python. The code below is the one which I am using and is receiving an error which I can't spot.

The code:

```
letterGrade = "F"
    if grade >= 90 :
            letterGrade = "A"
    elif grade >= 80 :
            letterGrade = "B"
    elif grade >= 70 :
            letterGrade = "C"
    elif grade >= 60 :
            letterGrade = "D"
```

The Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-4d6de02f92d4> in <module>
      1 #e
      2 letterGrade = "F"
----> 3 if grade >= 90 :
      4         letterGrade = "A"
      5 elif grade >= 80 :

NameError: name 'grade' is not defined
```

Comment: The error is quite explicit: the variable `grade` is not defined anywhere in the code you've provided.

Comment: Well where is `grade`? Where is there a variable named `grade` set to something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, a NameError is raised when you try to use a variable or a function name that is not valid. This means that you cannot declare a variable after you try to use it in your code. Python would not know what you wanted the variable to do.
Here, you missed to declare the variable grade. Inorder to handle this problem you can give a direct value to grade or make it as a input variable.
So, your code needs to be like this

```
grade = int(input()) or 75
    if grade >= 90 :
            letterGrade = "A"
    elif grade >= 80 :
            letterGrade = "B"
    elif grade >= 70 :
            letterGrade = "C"
    elif grade >= 60 :
            letterGrade = "D"
print(letterGrade)
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically the error is saying that there is no variable defined as 'grade' in your code. To fix this you would need to add the line below to above your current code.

```py
grade = 91
```

This would then set lettergrade equal to an 'A', or to whatever range your number grade is in (if you did not set it to 91 as I did).

The complete code would look something like this:

```py
grade = 91
letterGrade = "F"
    if grade >= 90 :
            letterGrade = "A"
    elif grade >= 80 :
            letterGrade = "B"
    elif grade >= 70 :
            letterGrade = "C"
    elif grade >= 60 :
            letterGrade = "D"
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this code as a part of our college assignment.

> This is a non-error giving code as the exception block handles the possible error which may occur during the execution.

```
def computegrade(score):

  ''' function which takes score prompted by user as a parameter and returns the designated score '''
  
  if score >= 90:
   return 'A'  
  
  elif score >= 80:
   return 'B'
    
  elif score >= 70:
   return 'C'
    
  elif score >= 60:
   return 'D'
    
  else: 
   return 'F'

try:                                               # try except block to check if user entered any invalid score
  score = int(input("Enter your score? "))
  if score > 100:                                  # the score can't be above 100 and so the user gets error message on doing so
    print('Error Value. The range of the score is between 0 and 100')
  else:
      grade = computegrade(score)
      print(f'You have got Grade {grade}')

except ValueError:
  print("Error Value. The range of the score is between 0 and 100. The entered value doesn't make sense")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).